# Azure output VM list with total storage for each VM

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, storage

I was wondering if it's actually possible to output this type of table, which represents each type of storage with their total size for each VM:

vmname | vmtype | total standard LRS storage | total standard GRS storage | total standard RA-GRS storage | total premium storage

I know it's not possible with Powershell and I'm not that skilled with C# for example. Get-AzureRmDisk doesn't show me any output, this means that no disk are managed disks. Is there any possibility to output this kind of table with any script?

Comment: Why should is not be possible with powershell? Ofc it is.

Comment: In which cmdlet disks storage type is stored? Only information about disks type I found under $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize, but this is not what I'm looking for.